# Architecture: basis for video broadcasting (1 Client app -> Web Server -> N Client Apps)

Tags: video, web-applications, broadcast

I am working on a personal project in which video broadcasting is a pivotal feature (think in Periscope or Meerkat). However, it is not clear to me what do involve to implement such feature and what do I need to learn also.

I am asking for help to get an intuition (big picture) about which are the fundamental concepts behind this piece of software.

- How should the video broadcast sent to a web server?. I suspect that this do not work in the same way that file upload do (using a multi part form).
- Is required a connection using sockets?
- How should the server expose the broadcast at the same time its receiving it?.
- Can something like this be done by a small team (3 - 5) or should I look for paid services that can solve this problem?

In the past, I have built many web applications so I am aware of most of the required components of them (HTTP request/response cycle, basic security, REST API, data bases, cache, etc.), however, I have never dealt with an application of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

There're two situation: For pre-recorded video file or for live video feed.
For video file:

1. Simple place the file on the server and done.(Oh you certainly need a player. But HTML5 already had) If you don't want people download easily, you can make some session validation or one time validation. If you really don't hope user download the video, you can use VOD streaming server like `Wowza Streaming Engine`.
2. What you mean?!
3. It's not a problem if you have fast enough CPU and network. But you maybe worry about availability. You can use some paid CDN for large instance. For failover and redundant you can also use VOD platform(it act as something like CDN but you might got backup server). I don't have experience about VOD. I guess something like aws(amazon) or sotalcloud will suitable for you.
4. According to clients you need to serve. Mostly worry about network traffic and CPU.

For live stream(including mixed video file and camera signal):

1. Some mixing/encoding soft/hardware will be needed. From my experience, `Wirecast`, `vMix` is stable enough to do that. If you only need enconding(from camera signal or a hardware vision mixer), `Flash Media Server`, `Wowza Streaming Engine` with capture hardware can done well also. And `Livestream Broadcasters` is a standalone streaming hardware will HDMI/SDI input and encoded network output. `VLC` can works but you need to fine tune the parameters in very deep. I tested VLC with a web server and caching policy can result good but really really complex on configuration. All softwares or hardwares mentioned above I had already tested or handed on with working configuration.
2. Same above
3. Same concept above and I tried Wowza(streaming cloud) and DaCast with acceptable result. They're both CDN like service and worry about entry point location(Like the proxy location which connect to your web server). Different location may affect performance, latency, smoothness and even stability. I can say DaCast doesn't works very good in China even entry point in China(Yeah, I may in HK and Macau and I go mainland China often). Maybe it's the problem of the China firewall not dacast.
4. Same above.

Oh yeah youtube is a good choice since it's feel and very strong and stable. But you may have some limitation. See https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853834?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your response. The main case is related to users creating a live broadcast from their cellphone (part 2 of your answer), so I guess I will need to worry about the encoding and not about the hardware. I will check Wowza and Flash, however, do you know how complex can it be to develop something like Wowza Streaming Engine or Flash Media Server?. Any idea of how Periscope, Meerkat or others solved this part of the equation?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I thought you're talking about stream from computer. Wowza and FMS is computer software maybe not suitable for you. What I know is, many phone have hardware acceleration for some codec. And maybe H.264 will be most popular today. What you need to worry is what kind of API can utitlize the hardware encoder.(Mostly only android, ios has good API and documentation for process media file, media stream(including encoder) and capture hardware).

Comment: And maybe you will also worry H.264 profile level. Coz it affect the bandwidth/quality ratio. Some cheap(relatively) device may only encode to lower-complex level. Also, you may not generate stream like HLS from a phone. Because it is distribution-oriented. It care about smoothness and availability more than real-time. Instead, rtsp and rtmp will be better choice. They're real-time(not reverse-able, but can cache a few second) and ignore any packet loss or mismatch. The app on the mobile can just pack the encoded stream into rtsp/rtmp and send.

Comment: And so you need a distribution server that re-mux the rstp/rtmp to HLS or other distribution format. To answer your question, write an app on mobile (for instance, ios) will not be so hard. Write the server with streaming platform API will also not quite hard. (So you can redirect the rstp/rtmp to platform's entry point without traffic to your server). If you try to write your own re-mux server, oh big challenge. I can say, re-mux is not hard(VLC and it's library can help you and free!). But hard to fine tune for distribution.

Comment: Wilson, I really appreciate your advice on this. Now, I know where to look for more information and I have a much clear vision of what it takes to build something like this.

Comment: Inform me after archived your target!

Comment: I will Wilson! Thanks again.